# How to calculate figure's size including all sub figures (that have separate edit parts) in GEF?

Tags: eclipse-gef, draw2d

I'm trying to draw diagram that contains a single entity which holds multiple elements inside. 
***My MVC structure looks something like this:***
**Model:** contains EntityModel.java and ElementModel.java which represents my model objects.
**View:** EntityFigure.java and ElementFigure.java
**Controller:** EntityEditPart.java and ElementEditPart.java

I'm overriding getModelChildren() in EntityEditPart.java to return list of ElementModel.java so that is how GEF knows that an element "belongs" to an entity.

Since I would like to calculate my entity's figure size and include the embedded elements in this calculation, I cannot call entityFigure.getPreferredSize() during createFigure() in EntityEditPart.java since at this point - the elements figures do not exists (createFigure() in ElementEditPart.java is not invoked yet).

I'm looking for a place to set my entity figure after all child figures were created. 
I though about overriding addNotify() in ElementEditPart.java, however, it is being called after creating a specific inner element and not after all elements created.

Any ideas?

Hope I was clear enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in an extension of

```
 refreshChildren()
```

method of an edit part, since all the child creation is done in refreshChildren() of superclass's (AbstractEditPart) refresh method:

```
public void refresh() {
    refreshVisuals();
    refreshChildren();
}
```

Or, you can just extend

```
refresh()
```